lazarus cross compiling from windows to PI Zero 2 - execute gives access violation
I've been using FPCupDeluxe to install a version of Lazarus that can cross compile projects to be runnable on a Raspberry PI Zero 2W. When running a simple executable I get:
larand@localhost:~ $ ./T1
An unhandled exception occurred at $00010E50:
EAccessViolation: Access violation
  $00010E50

Run command "readelf -a T1" shows:
    Displaying notes found in: .note.ABI-tag
readelf: Warning: Corrupt note: alignment 16, expecting 4 or 8
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6

I have tried to follow the instructions carefully but I must have missed something.
May this message: "Warning: Corrupt note: alignment 16, expecting 4 or 8" give any clues?
I know this is not so much of information but I have to start somewhere...
